# How can I figure out an unknown UART's speed?

Tags: fpga, serial, uart, linux

So I have a piece of hardware I'm reverse engineering. I believe I've found a UART on the board. I have an FPGA connected to it that just does:

```
ExtTX <= PCRX;
PCTX <= ExtRX;
```

So, in this way I can theoretically handle any speed the FTDI on my FPGA can(which is fairly fast). So, I have the hardware portion covered. Now though, using Linux(or Windows), how can I figure out what the speed and stop bits and other configuration options of the serial connection should be?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have any sort of a logic analyzer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to measure the shortest transition-transition time.

This will, assuming the bus you're looking at has a decently varied content, tell you the bit-time for the serial interface. You can then go from that to the overall baud rate.

---

Really though, if you're serious about doing reverse-engineering or any sort of electrical engineering at all, you will **need** an oscilloscope (and probably a logic analyzer), so you should think about buying one soon.

Comment: I've been looking at them, but man are they expensive!

Comment: @Earlz: You could build a logic analyser into your FPGA: http://www.sump.org/projects/analyzer/ - but you really do need a scope too :)

Comment: For that kind of speed, you can buy a cheap oscilloscope from e-bay, I bought one for $80 and it works great up to 1MHz.

Comment: @Earlz - Expensive? Hah, I think they've gotten ridiculously cheap! You can get a surprisingly capable scope for ~$400 these days.

Comment: @MartinThompson that's actually what I ended up doing, but now I'm off on a tangent because I couldn't get their Java client to work after 3 hours of tinkering with it. Apparently one of it's dependencies don't support 64bit machines, nor anything newer than Linux kernel 2.6.. So, I'm making my own minimalistic client

Answer (score 2):

With a little luck, brute forcing can sometimes be faster than pulling out your oscilloscope or logic analyzer (or your only option when you don't have this kind of equipment).

I have a USB<=>Serial cable lying around that I use for these challenges. I just connect GND and RxD wires from it to the circuit and just try to capture data. I usually start at 9600 8N1 (which is pretty common), where 9600 is the Baudrate, 8 is the number of data bits, N is short for no-parity and 1 is the number of stop bits.

The slow method is using a program like [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and configure it for every Baudrate you want to try, my fast method is [a Perl script](https://git.linformatronics.nl/gitweb/?p=cat_usbCable;a=summary) that I can access from the command line and takes the Baudrate as option, followed by a tool that hexdump's the data received. Here is an example (Linux):

```
cat_usbCable --baudrate=2400 | hexdump -C
00000000  7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.ELF............|
00000010  02 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00  40 13 40 00 00 00 00 00  |..>.....@.@.....|
00000020  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  c8 62 00 00 00 00 00 00  |@........b......|
00000030  00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00  09 00 40 00 1c 00 1b 00  |....@.8...@.....|
```

Common baudrates are: 300, 600, **1200**, 2400, 4800, **9600**, 14400, 19200, 38400, **57600**, **115200**.

Comment: The scope option works when your dealing with non standard rates like 125000. Only had that happen once tho...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a logic analyzer with built in RS232 decoder or an oscilloscope to probe the signals.

If you don't have those tools available you will probably need to write a decoder for your FPGA to calculate the bit and word timings using a reference clock.